# How do you tell if a TableCell is visible in the viewport?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a function that will scroll a `TableView` to a column/row if you tab(or focus to) to that cell. Problem is, I don't want it to scroll if the cell is already visible. I only want it to scroll to that column/row if the cell is not visible (in the ViewPort). Is there a way I can tell at any given time, if a cell is visible?

Comment: not supported - and simply knowing wouldn't help anyway: to improve the suboptimal scrolling you need both a custom tableSkin and a custom virtualFlow

Comment: @kleopatra it seems like the default TableSkin and VirtualFlow is the bane of most of my problems. Is this going to be fixed in later releases of JavaFX? Is someone even working on these types of issues?

Comment: don't know - I do it for customers quite often ;)

Comment: Does creating a custom TableSKin or Virtual Flow use private APIs? Does it break compatibility with later releases of Java?